# Cannot invoke observe on a background thread When calling live data method

Tags: java, android

need your help.

I have a qr code reader that receiving me some object.

In other side I have LiveData object from SQLite (Room).

When i receive the object from QRScanner I'm trying to call live data object from database to check if it's already exit (by string).

But I have error that says:

```
E/CameraSource: Exception thrown from receiver.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke observe on a background thread
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:462)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:189)
        at com.msapps.movieapp.view.fragments.QRCodeScannerFragment.onQRScanned(QRCodeScannerFragment.java:108)
        at com.msapps.movieapp.view.fragments.-$$Lambda$PGtfO3ziWSk5mvcCZ1yOj6ZqQtU.onQRScanned(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.msapps.movieapp.utils.QRScanner$2.receiveDetections(QRScanner.java:100)
```

Here is my QRScanner.

```
        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                MoviesResponse moviesResponse = gson.fromJson(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue, MoviesResponse.class);
                iCallback.onQRScanned(moviesResponse);
            }
        }
    });
}

public interface QRCodeInterface{
    void onQRScanned(MoviesResponse response);

}
```

With the iCallback interface I'm passing data to fragment:

And in the fragment I do the next:

```
@Override
public void onQRScanned(MoviesResponse response) {
    mMoviesViewModel.getMovieByTitle(response.getTitle()).observe(QRCodeScannerFragment.this, new Observer<MoviesResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(MoviesResponse moviesResponse) {
            mTVMovieTitle.setText(response.getTitle());
        }
    });
}
```

GetMovieByTitle from repo class:

```
public LiveData<MoviesResponse> getMovieByTitle(String movieTitle) {
    return movieDao.getMovie(movieTitle);
}
```

And a query from Dao

```
@Query("select * from movies where movie_title ==:title")
LiveData<MoviesResponse> getMovie(String title);
```

Can some one help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get data from Room on a background thread, do not use `LiveData`. Either:

- Use a synchronous method (since you are already on a background thread), or
- Use RxJava, or
- Use Kotlin coroutines (once you Kotlin-ize your project)

This may require you to have parallel methods in your DAO, if you need to get the data both from the main application thread (using `LiveData`) and from a background thread:

```java
@Query("select * from movies where movie_title ==:title")
LiveData<MoviesResponse> getMovie(String title);

@Query("select * from movies where movie_title ==:title")
MoviesResponse getMovieSynchronously(String title);
```